# How to target only the front page (not subsequent paginated pages) in theme/plugin?

Tags: functions, frontpage

I'd like to switch on the front page ONLY. Not subsequent paginated pages (like ?paged=2). I want to output certain output only on the "true" front page of the site.

I've tried:

```
<?php if (is_front_page() && get_query_var('paged', 1) == 1 || 0): ?>
```

but this only works if the `paged` variable is present (ex: `domain.com?paged=1`).

Comment: What do consider as the *'true"* front page? Is this the page set as static front page, or the homepage/blogpage

Comment: @peter I would consider the "true" front page to be either the static front page set by the user or the first paginated blog "homepage", depending on the setting the admin has chosen in the backend.

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted?! Was I not clear enough?? Is this a thing that nobody else has wanted to do??

Comment: I cannot answer for the downvote as it wasn't me, but I will try to post an answer on what you have posted

Comment: Drupal has is_front_page(). Perhaps I will look at the code for that function and draw some inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconception about `is_front_page()`. Lets look at the source:

```
public function is_front_page() {
    // most likely case
    if ( 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && $this->is_home() )
        return true;
    elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) && $this->is_page( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

So from the above, `is_front_page()` will return true on

- The static front page (*when reading setting is set as `Front page`*) and every paged page of the static front page. `/page/2/` etc will return true as it is just a paged page of the static front page
- The homepage when the reading setting is set to *`Your latest posts`*, as well as every paged page of the post page.

`is_front_page()` will return false on:

- The blogpage when a static front page is set and the posts page are set with *`Posts page`*. However, `is_home()` will return true here
- Any other page that is not the homepage or static front page.

What you are thinking of is `is_paged()`. This conditional will return false on the first page of a paginated query, and will return true on other page of a paginated query.

With this in mind, you would probably need the following

```
if (    is_front_page() // Can change to is_home()
     && !is_paged() // Use the NOT operator to return true on page one, false after that
) {
    // Do what you need to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pieter! That is exactly what I was looking for. You're right, I was confusing `is_front_page()` with something that it was not and I didn't know about `is_paged()` but imagined that it must exist. Thank you for your help!